# get array of checkbox values from post

Tags: php, html

Here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    if (is_array($_POST['type'])) {
        echo "IS ARRAY!!!!!!!!";
    } 
    else {
        echo "IS NOT ARRAY!!!";
    }
}
?>
```

and..

```
<div id="player" class="group">
    <form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?> id="playerform" method="post">
<?php
for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($_SESSION['playercharacter']->defendAgainst); $j++) {    
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['playercharacter']-> 
defendAgainst[$j]; ?> />
<?php    
}        
?>            
    </form>    
</div>
```

Thing is....$_POST['type'] is just a single value rather than an array.. How do i get ALL checked values? Thanks for your time...

Comment: for `type[]` the `$_POST['type']` should be an array

Comment: i know that is what i am confused about $_POST['type'] is not an array!

Comment: check everything again, rewrite it in new file and test again, you can add some test values for testing

Comment: try adding quotes around your checkbox value - `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['playercharacter']->defendAgainst[$j]; ?>"`. It may not be causing the issue, but sometimes it does. Also, check all your form elements below your loop to make sure you do not have another element with `<input name="type" ...`

Comment: Thx Sean, the missing quotes was what caused it!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you

```
 <form action="" method="post" >
            <?php 
            for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'<br/>';       
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" >
        </form>

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


        $arr=array();
        foreach($_POST['type'] as $key=>$value)
        {
            $arr[$key]=$value;
        }    
        var_dump($arr);


}
```